# mysql user@% can access from localhost

Tags: mysql, localhost

I was always told that "%" means every host except localhost.

However I have created a user4@"%" and I can connect to from localhost.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N8Dh.png)

So now I am a bit confused regarding this. Can anyone clarify this for me, please?

Comment: Is there another entry for `user4`?  Or maybe `"%"@"%"?  Switch to the sister forum dba.stackexchange.com if you don't get satisfaction in serverfault.

Comment: Nope. That's the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was always told that "%" means every host except localhost.

This is plain wrong.

% is a wildcard. It [matches 0 or more of any character](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html):

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use _ to match any single character and % to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters)

Thus % in the hostname field matches *any* host, including localhost.

Comment: But, I think that user@host is treated specially.

Comment: In the documentation says that  @"localhost" is treated differently on UNIX systems because they use a UNIX socket as protocol for local connections. However it doesn't say what's the difference. According to my teacher, user1@"%" should not be allowed to connect to the server locally but my tests prove otherwise.

Comment: The client defaults to attempting socket communication for localhost. That doesn't change mysql's wildcard handling however. Your tests are however entirely right, and matches the documentation re. wildcards - and your teacher is wrong.